# How to get AAD user token for unit testing based on logged in user?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I have a service that needs to call a downstream service using AAD user token that I am trying to unit test.
I am logged into the Windows machine. Is it possible within xUnit to acquire a token based on logged in user on the machine or logged in user in Visual Studio?

I have tried code given below and it gives exception MsalClientException “WS-Trust endpoint not found in metadata document.”

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-integrated-windows-authentication.md#net